# wordpress: previous/next link needs to include certain categories only

Tags: wordpress

I am currently using wordpress 3.6.

Since 3.3 the excluded_categories parameter is deprecated inside previous_post_link(), see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link#Resources.

What is the recommended way to explicitly include or exclude categories now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_adjacent_post`

```
$in_same_cat = false;/true
$excluded_categories = '';//cat
$previous = true;//false
$previous_post = get_adjacent_post($in_same_cat,$excluded_categories,$previous);

$in_same_cat = false;//true
$excluded_categories = '';//cat
$previous = false;//true
$next_post = get_adjacent_post($in_same_cat,$excluded_categories,$previous);
```

[**get_adjacent_post**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post)